# can't find gmplot marker after doing pyinstaller

Tags: python, google-maps-markers, pyinstaller, markers, gmplot

I am using gmplot to plot markers on google map. Everything works well before doing pyinstaller to make an exe file. I am not able to do gmp.draw to draw the marker into my map.html. There are no error shown while doing pyinstaller.
When I executing my exe file, the error shows that

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "test.py", line 792, in plotmap
    gmap.draw('map.html')
  File "site-packages\gmplot\gmplot.py", line 1050, in draw
  File "site-packages\gmplot\gmplot.py", line 1121, in _write_html
  File "site-packages\gmplot\gmplot.py", line 1187, in write_points
  File "site-packages\gmplot\gmplot.py", line 1228, in write_point
  File "site-packages\gmplot\gmplot.py", line 164, in __init__
  File "site-packages\gmplot\utility.py", line 68, in _get_embeddable_image
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI366362\\gmplot\\markers/000000.png'
```

I tried to fix it by adding

```
gmp.coloricon = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/%s/"
```

but nothing change.

Here are my codes about the gmplot

```
import gmplot
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def plotmap():
    # Create the map plotter:
    apikey = '' # (your API key here)
    gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.766956, -122.448481, 14, apikey=apikey)

    # Outline the Golden Gate Park:
    golden_gate_park = zip(*[
        (37.771269, -122.511015),
        (37.773495, -122.464830),
        (37.774797, -122.454538),
        (37.771988, -122.454018),
        (37.773646, -122.440979),
        (37.772742, -122.440797),
        (37.771096, -122.453889), 
        (37.768669, -122.453518),
        (37.766227, -122.460213),
        (37.764028, -122.510347)
    ])
    gmap.polygon(*golden_gate_park, color='cornflowerblue', edge_width=10)

    # Highlight some attractions:
    attractions_lats, attractions_lngs = zip(*[
        (37.769901, -122.498331),
        (37.768645, -122.475328),
        (37.771478, -122.468677),
        (37.769867, -122.466102),
        (37.767187, -122.467496),
        (37.770104, -122.470436)
    ])
    gmap.scatter(attractions_lats, attractions_lngs, color='#3B0B39', size=40, marker=False)

    # Mark a hidden gem:
    gmap.marker(37.770776, -122.461689, color='cornflowerblue')

    # Draw the map:
    gmap.draw('map.html')
    webbrowser.open('map.html')



root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text= "plot on map", command=plotmap)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get the answer on github, the problem is that there is no such data in that dir, instead the gmplot market will be inside site-package\gmplot. Thus, the problem is due to pyinstaller not link the package. To solve this, we need to use hook to hook the data (marker)

1.add a directory “hooks” and put hooks-gmplot.py inside. Note that the .py file need to be hook-the_package_need_to_hook.py ,or else it will fail

2.inside the hook-gmplot.py, put the followin

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('gmplot')
#datas = collect_data_files('C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\gmplot') will raise input error
```

3.type the following pyinstaller command in the CMD

```
pyinstaller -F test.py —additional-hooks-dir=hooks
```